# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pos'

Tags: python

Появилась такая ошибка, а я не знаю, как ее решить. Только перешла к vpython. Можете помочь, пожалуйста.

```
from vpython import*
sphere(vector(pos=(-5,0,0)), radius=0.5, color=color.red)
```

Comment: ну судя по тексту ошибки функция не узнает аргумент `pos`. Попробуйте `addpos`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы перепутали местами vector и pos.
Нужно так:

```
sphere(pos=vector(-5,0,0), radius=0.5, color=color.red)
```